# I have a recipe that calls for a Cubanelle Pepper, but my dad can't eat peppers.

Tags: substitutions, chili-peppers

I've got a recipe that asks for a Cubanelle Pepper. I was going to just leave it out, but I'm not sure how much it's going to alter the flavor.  It's a flounder and scallop saute in a garlic cream sauce.

Additional ingredients: Italian parsley, lemon zest, Greek seasoning, corn, green onions

Is there anything I can add to help make up the flavor?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that Cubanelle peppers are not hot peppers — they're similar to green bell peppers. So if your father's restriction is restricted to hot peppers, then he'd be just fine.

Otherwise, there's nothing else quite like the flavor of peppers (other than paprika, which of course, is made from peppers). Your recipe has so many other flavorful ingredients, that it's sure to be delicious if you simply leave out the Cubanelle pepper.

However, ***celery*** might be a good substitute in your recipe, being similar in color and texture to Cubanelle peppers. The flavor of celery is subtle and would work quite well with the other ingredients you listed.

Comment: Thank you...I think I'll have a little on hand and ask him - you never know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed fine for decades simply skipping any peppers in recipes. It won't be the same as with peppers. Whether allergic or simply having severe dislike for them, the difference won't be a problem for someone who cannot eat peppers.

Comment: That's what I'm probably going to do...it's what I've always done in the past when I've cooked for him.  I just figured I'd ask in case anyone had any ideas I hadn't thought of. And I agree...he won't miss it :)   Thanks very much!